# Can I add a new constructor to an existing class?

Tags: scala, constructor, extension-methods, implicit

In Scala, it's possible to use an [implicit class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) to add a new method to an object:

```
implicit class IntWithTimes(x: Int) {
  def times[A](f: => A): Unit = {
    def loop(current: Int): Unit =
      if(current > 0) {
        f
        loop(current - 1)
      }
    loop(x)
  }
}
```

Is there a mechanism for adding new constructors? Whether `new Int("1")` or `Int("1")` or something similar.

Comment: You could just add a pseudo constructor couldn't you?

Comment: Carl, could you please provide an example of the expected syntax of that imaginary additional constructor? If that is `new TargetClass(new params list)`, then No, such constructors can be added only by the `TargetClass` iteslf. If you mean something else - we need an example of what you are aiming for.

Comment: @SergGr I've clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the answer is No. To add a constructor or `apply` to `TargetClass` method you should control the source of the `class TargetClass` or its companion `object TargetClass` both of which must be in the same file.

If your target is actually `Int`, then it can be made to work with a following hack:

```
object IntEx {
  def Int(s: String): Int = s.toInt
}

import IntEx._

val v: Int = Int("123")
```

This hack works only because `Int` has no companion object and thus `Int` is resolved to `IntEx.Int` method. It will not work for any class with defined companion object including any `case class` because it will take precedence in name resolution.

Still the most important question is probably why you want it to look like a constructor rather than be an explicit factory method? I mean what's really wrong with

```
object IntEx {
  def intFromString(s: String): Int = s.toInt
}
val v2: Int = IntEx.intFromString("123")
```

or

```
object IntFromString {
  def apply(s: String): Int = s.toInt
}
val v3: Int = IntFromString("123")
```

Comment: One example usage would be when defining 128-bit integers. Maybe I want to copy the APIs of `Int` and `Long` etc. as closely as possible for reason of ergonomics/discoverability, which would mean providing e.g. `BigDecimal` with a constructor that takes my new type.

Comment: @CarlPatenaudePoulin, you can take another approach similar to what Scala's `RichString`/`StringLike` does i.e. add to your `Int128` method like `toBigDecimal`. I don't think anybody really cares about using specifically constructor-like thing as long as there is a clear way to make the conversion.